# Derivative of $\sqrt{x^{2}}$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm suppose to calculate the derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2}$ when $x=0$.
I.e., I need to determine $f'(0)$.  I worked it out this way:

$\begin{align} f'(0 )&= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\\ \\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^2} - 0}{x-0}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{x}\\ \\
&=1\end{align}$

I know I'm doing something wrong, because the solution says there is no derivative, But I don't know why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue is the following: $\sqrt{x^{2}}=|x|$, not $x$. So your problem reduces to 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|x|}{x}$$
which does not exist. This is because the right-hand limit ($1$) and left-hand limit $(-1)$ do not agree.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. So in order for the derivative to exist, both sides of the limit have to be equal. Got it. Ty